# Proportion of Normal distributions such that sum of them is again some fixed Normal distribution

Tags: r

Suppose you know that you have n cities each follows some Normal distribution of some feature and you also know the same for the whole country. Now you are asked to find the proportion of the cities such that the mixture additive model of the n normal distribution gives you the same distribution Of the country. You can have the estimates of the parameters for both city and country level. How will you proceed?

Anyway I propose one solution. If you assume the following proportions as p_i for the i th city, then it boils down to

```
Sum of Mu_i* p_i =Mu of country level
sum of Sigma_i^2*p_i^2= Sigma of country level
```

These are the constraints and we need to minimize the distance between the distribution at the country level and the postulated distribution ( i.e. sum of p_i* Phi (Mu_i, Sigma_i^2)). And now we need to find the optimum p_i.

Is the solution on the right track?